# How to insert line break in bootstrap alert -bootstrap MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am setting validation error in view as follows

```
   @if (TempData["ErrorMsg"] != null)
        {
            if (TempData["ErrorMsg"].ToString() != "")
            {
                <div id="danger-alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    <strong>Warning!</strong> @TempData["ErrorMMsg"]
                </div>
            }
        }
```

Also i am setting validation message in server side as follows

```
  StringBuilder sbMsg= new StringBuilder();
  sbMsg.AppendLine("Duplicate Entry." + "<br/>");
  sbMsg.AppendLine("Duplicate id." + "<br/>");
  TempData["ErrorMsg"] = sbMsg.toString();
  return View("AddEntry", model);
```

But in bootstrap alert,line break is not happening and it is showing "br" tag inside error message and showing it as single line. How i can insert a line break in validation message that are displayed in bootstrap alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["ErrorMsg"].ToString()))
{
        <div id="danger-alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Warning!</strong> @Html.Raw(TempData["ErrorMsg"]);
        </div>
}
```

Comment: @Adlorem..Thank you so  much..It works like a charm...